# Merge cells with duplicate values in a column without changing the adjacent column

Tags: vba, excel

My Worksheet looks like this:

> ```
>    COL A   COL B           COL C
> ```
>
> PHGDCB01   HGCBTA01    PHHG.HGCRUNT.RUNSCH.ESDS
>
> PHGDCB01   HGCBTA01    PHHG.HGERORM.ERRMSG.KSDS
>
> PHGDCB01   HGCBTA01    PHHG.HGCONTM.CONTRACT.KSDS
>
> PHGDCB01   HGCBTA01    PHHG.HGBRANM.BRANCH.KSDS
>
> PHGDCB01   HGCBTA01    PHHG.HGBACUM.BRANCH.ACCUM.KSDS
>
> PHGDCB01   HGCBTA01    PHHG.HGCONTT.CB.TXN.KSDS
>
> PHGDCB01   HGCBTA01    PHHG.HGCONTT.CB.TXN.ALTX.PATH

What i want is something like this

```
        PHGDCB01   HGCBTA01   PHHG.HGCRUNT.RUNSCH.ESDS

                              PHHG.HGERORM.ERRMSG.KSDS
                              PHHG.HGCONTM.CONTRACT.KSDS
                              PHHG.HGBRANM.BRANCH.KSDS
                              PHHG.HGBACUM.BRANCH.ACCUM.KSDS
                              PHHG.HGCONTT.CB.TXN.KSDS
```

This is the code I've tried to write:

```
Sub Macro3()        
    For MY_ROWS = Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
        If Range("A" & MY_ROWS).Value = Range("A" & MY_ROWS - 1).Value Then
            Range("A" & MY_ROWS).ClearContents
        End If
    Next MY_ROWS
End sub
```

Its merely deleting the duplicate values keeping only one value. Its not actualy merging. I had to manually merge with blank cells. Why?

Comment: What is being merged?  Are you saying all COL C's content being merged into 1 cell while their respective col A&B value is the same?  Furthermore, on your example, is "PHHG.HGCRUNT.RUNSCH.ESDS" suppose to be merged as well?

Comment: The values of column A and Column B are getting merged while the value of Column C remains the same.
In the example Column A value 'PHGDCB01' and column B value ' HGCBTA01' are getting merged and values of col C remains same.

Comment: I will try to provide an answer, meanwhile, you could look at skiingflea's answer for ref

Answer (score 0):

Clearcontents won't do any merging. You will need to call .Merge on a suitable range like this:

```
Range("A1:A5").Merge
```

You will need to figure out the A1:A5 part based on where the values in column A change. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you skiingflea for your suggestion. :)
I needed that

Answer (score 0):

The code below will merge column A:

```
Sub Macro3()
    For MY_ROWS = Range("B65536").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If MY_ROWS = 2 And Range("A" & MY_ROWS).Value = Range("A" & MY_ROWS - 1).Value Then
    Range("A" & MY_ROWS).ClearContents
    Range("A" & MY_ROWS + i & ":A" & MY_ROWS - 1).Merge
    End If
        If Range("A" & MY_ROWS).Value = Range("A" & MY_ROWS - 1).Value Then
            i = i + 1
            Range("A" & MY_ROWS).ClearContents
        Else:
            Range("A" & MY_ROWS + i & ":A" & MY_ROWS).Merge
            i = 0
        End If
    Next MY_ROWS

End Sub
```

You should able to figure out Column B with the same approach

Comment: Thank you Alex.That is awesome.Just what I needed.You are great

Comment: Glad it helps.  Please also accept the answer so other helper knows this issue no longer need helps, thanks